# Batch Merge subtitles into MKV file using MKVToolNix

Tags: batch, subtitles, matroska

I am currently trying to merge external subtitle files (.ass files) into an mkv file, but am facing problems with looping.

My latest attempt at this:

```
set mkvmerge="C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"  
set output_folder=G:\tada kun\muxed  
set counter = 01  
set test='G:\tada kun\subs\\[Kaya] Tada-Kun Wa Koi O Shinai - %counter% (Bd 1080P X.265 Flac).ass'  
for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do call %mkvmerge% -o "%output_folder%\%%~na.mkv"   --audio-tracks 1 --language 0:jpn --default-track 0:yes --language 1:jpn --default-track 1:yes  "%%a" --language 0:eng --default-track 0:yes "%test%" --attachment-name OpenSans-Semibold.ttf --attach-file ^"G:\tada kun\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf^"  --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:0
```

I'm not sure how to increment counter here, but the main problem is that counter doesn't show when I call the test variable. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `set counter = 01` - this creates a variable called `counter ` (note the trailing space). Use `set counter=01`

Comment: @DavidPostill oh dam.. I didn't realise that haha. Thanks so much! If u don't mind answering another question, would you by any chance know how to increment counter within the 5th line here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `counter` doesn't show when I call the test variable.

> ```
> set counter = 01
> ```

This creates a variable called `counter` (note the trailing space).

The correct way to do this is:

```
set counter=01
```

And to cater for the times that the value may contain a space:

```
set "counter=01"
```

In your case, however (using a counter) you need to use a different form of `set`:

```
set /a counter=0
```

Where `/a` allows you to use arithmetic expressions on the variable.

---

#### I'm not sure how to increment `counter` here.

Use:

```
set /a counter+=1
```

To retrieve the value is a little more tricky. First you have to enable delayed expansion using

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

This allows variables to be evaluated at execution time rather than at parse time. If you don't do this then variables in loops will expand to the the initial value and not the updated value.

Then to retrieve the value you use `!counter!` instead of `%counter%`.

When using `!counter!` expansion is performed each time the line is executed, or for each loop in a `for` loop.

---

#### Putting it all together

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mkvmerge="C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"  
set output_folder=G:\tada kun\muxed  
set /a counter=0
for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do (
  set "test=G:\tada kun\subs\\[Kaya] Tada-Kun Wa Koi O Shinai - !counter! (Bd 1080P X.265 Flac).ass"
  %mkvmerge% -o "%output_folder%\%%~na.mkv" --audio-tracks 1 --language 0:jpn --default-track 0:yes --language 1:jpn --default-track 1:yes "%%a" --language 0:eng --default-track 0:yes "!test!" --attachment-name OpenSans-Semibold.ttf --attach-file ^"G:\tada kun\OpenSans-Semibold.ttf^"  --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:0
  set /a counter+=1
  )
endlocal
```

Note:

- `set test...` has been moved inside the `for` loop and `"`s used instead of `'`s.
- `"%test%"` has been replace by `"!test!"` to use delayed (execution) time expansion

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [For /r - Loop through sub-folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)
- [Set - Environment Variable - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Comment: Thank you!!! I have spent ages trying to work this out. Thanks to you, I have finally got it working! :)